# Ffmpeg frame extraction with Nvidia GPU acceleration throws "Output file #0 does not contain any stream"

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia, codec, nvdec

I am trying to use nvidia gpu accelerated decoder api with ffmpeg, to extract all frames from a video file (`.MTS`) to a folder, but it looks like it's failing for some reason; I could not find an answer or similar issues.

Command used:

`ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -c:v mpeg2_cuvid -i raw_video.MTS -q:v 2 -f image2 output_folder/image_%05d.jpg`

Traceback:

```
ffmpeg version n4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.0 (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[mpegts @ 0x563fcc5616c0] start time for stream 0 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 0x563fcc5616c0] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 0x563fcc5616c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mpeg2video (HDMV / 0x564D4448), none(tv)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'raw_video.MTS':
  Duration: 00:07:15.68, start: 1010.210356, bitrate: 41186 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: mpeg2video (HDMV / 0x564D4448), none(tv), 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080
Output #0, image2, to 'output_folder/image_%05d.jpg':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

I am pretty sure `-hwaccel cuvid -c:v mpeg2_cuvid` is correct as the file type seems to be MPEG-2 in the file properties, but similar issues happen with the other cuvid decoders as well:

[image]

I have also tried to run without `-c:v` flag but then a cuda error is raised and it runs on the cpu:

`[h264 @ 0x55949e6d7e00] decoder->cvdl->cuvidCreateDecoder(&decoder->decoder, params) failed -> CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE: invalid argument
[h264 @ 0x55949e6d7e00] Failed setup for format cuda: hwaccel initialisation returned error.`

Any help will be much appreciated.

### Edit:

- OS: Arch Linux
- GPU: Nvidia 1050Ti
- CUDA Version: 10.2
- NVIDIA-SMI: 440.82

### Edit 2:

```
ffmpeg version n4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.0 (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x557143911700] no frame!
[mpegts @ 0x55714390c540] PES packet size mismatch
Input #0, mpegts, from 'raw_video.MTS':
  Duration: 00:18:30.97, start: 113.284733, bitrate: 16850 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Share the log for `ffmpeg -i raw_video.MTS`

Comment: @Gyan added output!

Comment: The video stream is h264, not mpeg2. Use `-c:v h264_cuvid`

Comment: This was actually the first one I tried and it seems to result in another error:
`Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!`

Comment: Add `-vf hwdownload,format=yuv420p` after the input

Comment: @Gyan still getting an error ( a different one but still):
`[hwdownload @ 0x55b68b22de80] Invalid output format yuv420p for hwframe download.
[Parsed_hwdownload_0 @ 0x55b68b22dd40] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_hwdownload_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!`

Comment: Change format to `nv12`

Comment: @Gyan this actually worked! If you want to add a formal answer with explanationI will upvote and accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The video codec is actually `h264`. MPEG2-TS is a container/packaging format and need not contain only MPEG-2 video streams.

When decoding a video using a hardware decoder such as `cuvid`, the decoded frames are in an hardware-specific data layout in hardware device memory. Before they can be transferred to system memory, they need to be converted to an acceptable layout.

Add the filters hwdownload to copy the frames to system memory, and a format filter immediately afterwards to specify the downloaded format for hwdownload. `nv12` is a variant of `yuv420p` for which a hW->SW conversion is available in ffmpeg.

`ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i raw_video.MTS -vf hwdownload,format=nv12 -vsync 0 -q:v 2 -f image2 output_folder/image_%05d.jpg`